# PHP Regex: How to get optional text if present?

Tags: php, regex

Let's take an example of following string:

```
$string = "length:max(260):min(20)";
```

In the above string, `:max(260):min(20)` is optional. I want to get it if it is present otherwise only `length` should be returned.
I have following regex but it doesn't work:

```
/(.*?)(?::(.*?))?/se
```

It doesn't return anything in the array when I use `preg_match` function.

Remember, there can be something else than above string. Maybe like this:

```
$string = "number:disallow(negative)";
```

Is there any problem in my regex or PHP won't return anything? Dumping `preg_match` returns `int 1` which means the string matches the regex.

Fully Dumped:

```
int 1
array (size=2)
  0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: What do you get if you dump the match array, and why are you using `e` modifier???

Comment: Maybe `/([^:]+)(:.*)?/` ?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Edited my question. IDK, I tried to make my own regex but it didn't work then I had to search web and I found a ASP.net related post which suggested the similar regex like above with both `s` and `e` modifiers.

Comment: @revo It works perfectly! Can you explain the regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using single character (`.`) matching in the case of being lazy, at the very beginning. So it stops at the zero position. If you change your `preg_match` function to `preg_match_all` you'll see the captured groups.

Another problem is with your Regular Expression. You're killing the engine. Also `e` modifier is deprecated many many decades before!!! and yet it was used in `preg_replace` function only.

Don't use `s` modifier too! That's not needed.

This works at your case:

```
/([^:]+)(:.*)?/
```

[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/eX1eC8/1)

Comment: Oh! I've explained my usage of `s` and `e` modifiers in my comment below question.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to prepare a regex which can probably solve your issue and also add some value to it

this regex will not only match the optional elements but will also capture in key value pair

**Regex**

```
/(?<=:|)(?'prop'\w+)(?:\((?'val'.+?)\))?/g
```

**Test string**

```
length:max(260):min(20)
length
number:disallow(negative)
```

**Result**

- MATCH 1

  - prop [0-6]   `length`

- MATCH 2

  - prop [7-10]  `max`
  - val  [11-14] `260`

- MATCH 3

  - prop [16-19] `min`
  - val  [20-22] `20`

- MATCH 4

  - prop [24-30] `length`

- MATCH 5

  - prop [31-37] `number`

- MATCH 6

  - prop [38-46] `disallow`
  - val  [47-55] `negative`

try [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/aM4zW9/1)

---

**EDIT**

I think I understand what you meant by duplicate array with different key, it was due to named captures eg. prop & val

here is the revision without named capturing

**Regex**

```
/(?<=:|)(\w+)(?:\((.+?)\))?/
```

**Sample code**

```
$str = "length:max(260):min(20)";
$str .= "\nlength";
$str .= "\nnumber:disallow(negative)";

preg_match_all("/(?<=:|)(\w+)(?:\((.+?)\))?/",
    $str,
    $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => length
            [1] => max(260)
            [2] => min(20)
            [3] => length
            [4] => number
            [5] => disallow(negative)
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => length
            [1] => max
            [2] => min
            [3] => length
            [4] => number
            [5] => disallow
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 260
            [2] => 20
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => negative
        )
)
```

try [demo here](http://ideone.com/grJUgZ)

Comment: Nice but can you make it so it does not produce `prop` and `val` as separate array? Its fine to have them in at indices `[1]` and `[2]`. I'm using `preg_match_all` right now.

Comment: do you need captures as `length`, `max(260)` & `min(20)` or `length` & `max(260):min(20)` or anything else?

Comment: You have posted an awesome regex. I was going to write another for the `max(260):min(20)` part. Can you make it a little neat so it won't create 2 arrays with same values but different keys? Check using `preg_match_all` and you'l know what I'm talking about.

Comment: Could you provide your expected result from the test string in the answer? current output is here http://ideone.com/grJUgZ

Comment: Hey man, I needed exactly that which you added in the edit. Thanks.